# How to import product excel data list into magento database

Tags: product

My client has more than 1000 products data having title, price, description, image etc.

We want to import all product list into magento system. We have searched many portal but they are using complex steps.

Can we import it in simple steps. We don't want to enter it one by one. It will consume more hours.

Comment: Have a look on https://www.cobby.io/en/

Answer (score 1):

**Dataflow:**
Magento comes with Dataflow. Although it's not the best importer for a basic file it'll do a fine job. Dataflow comes with several default import profiles but you can also define your own profiles.

You can read more about dataflow here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/introduction-to-magento-dataflow.

**AvS_FastSimpleImport:** for more complicated imports try FastSimpleImport. It's not standard in Magento and will need some tweaking but it'll do a better job than Dataflow https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport

Answer (score 0):

We have been given access to a beta that is direct Excel to Magento SaaS autoload avoiding the technical steps, if your client wants to beta test we can arrange for them to have a full access account in return.